# Objects mutability: changing the copy of objects in local environment affects global environment

Tags: python, immutability

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def my_fun(x):
    x[x>2] = 2
    y = 2 * x
    return y
sigma = pd.Series(np.linspace(0, 3, 80))
print(sigma.max())  # 3
my_fun(sigma)
print(sigma.max())  # 2
```

Here the problem is that the copy `x` of the mutable object sigma is changed inside a local environment, affecting sigma itself. How to elegantly rewrite `my_fun` in order to avoid to change the mutable object sigma? The input and output of my_fun must be of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a handle to a copy of the object to your function instead of a handle to the actual object.

```
my_fun(sigma.copy())
```

Edit: If you are worried about forgetting to pass the copy you could move creating the copy into the function. But then you would have to assume that the object x has a .copy()-function, which might limit its uses.

```
def my_fun(x_original):
    x = x_original.copy()
    x[x>2] = 2
    y = 2 * x
    return y
```

Comment: If the user forgets to provide the the .copy() object, my_fun would silently change the global environment. Therefore, I'm not sure to label this approach as elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Only look at `my_func`, you're doing three operations there.

```
a = x > 2
x[a] = 2
b = x * 2
```

- The first creates a new list of booleans. This doesn't mutate the array, and instead creates a new list with new object. This means when you call `sigma.max()` you don't get `True`.
- The second line then mutates `x` - you're not getting a new array back, you're mutating the data. (The problem)
- In the third line you create a new list where each item in the list is doubled.

And so you want to create a new list, and then mutate the data. You can do this by performing the third operation first.
And so you really want:

```
def my_fun(x):
    b = 2*x
    b[b>4] = 4
    return b
```

Comment: Your approach works in this particular case, but it assumes that we can perform the first operation b = 2*x, and it might not be the case if b = 2*np.log(x) where x can be negative. Therefore, the need to apply operations on x first. I've upvoted but I'm going to wait a bit before accepting an answer.